# Using datetick to label x axis: but don't show the last tick label

Tags: matlab, date, plot, axis-labels

Does anyone know how to remove the last ticklabel on a plot in Matlab AFTER using the datetick function to put the labels there?
I am plotting Y data and X dates (years and months converted to a datenum).

Then I am using the following to plot the year labels on the xaxis:

```
close all;clear all;clc;
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('data.xlsx');
yr = num(:,1);
mth= num(:,2);
data= num(:,3);

dates=datenum(yr,mth,1);
plot(dates,data,'r-.','linewidth',2);
dateFormat = 10;
datetick('x',dateFormat)
```

I would like to remove the last tick label, as it is including a year that isn't in the datset (presumably Matlab is optimising the distance between ticks and interpolating to the next year).

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37612557/edit) your question to include the whole code needed to plot your figure with the dateticks. Additionally, please clarify whether you want to remove *the last* or *the first and last* datetick.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the ticks you want on your chart first, e.g.:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', x_values_you_want_ticks_at);
```

Then use `datetick` with `'keepticks'` option, which will preserve your ticks location:

```
datetick(gca, 'x', dateFormat, 'keepticks');
```

Comment: The data runs between the years 1880:2015. With my code above, the xlabels run in 20 year increments (1880:20:2020). I don't want 2020 to show up on the x-axis. Ideally, I'd include 2015, but it's not critical.  I tried to implement what you suggested above with: 'set(gca, 'XTick', 1880:20:2015);' , as well as :'set(gca, 'XTick', {'1880', '1900','1920','1940','1960','1980','2000','2015'});' . Since the xticks are based on the datenum values, the former just caused all the labels to disappear. The latter threw an error regarding 'Conversion to double from cell is not possible'.